# Select statement in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Does anyone know how to use their tables and columns from pre-existing databases in a pl/sql command. I am using something from Oracles webpage to use as an example.

```
SQL> declare

2    v_line varchar2(40):= '&v_string';

3  begin

4    v_line := 'Hello '||v_line;

5    dbms_output.put_line (v_line);

6  end;

7  /



old 2:   v_line varchar2(40):= '&v_string';

New 2:   v_line varchar2(40):= 'Thomas';



Hello Thomas



PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

I am wanting to be able to manipulate the data from above. Lets say I have a table called name_s and I have columns called n_first and n_last and I want to use those columns to output 'Hello Thomas' but using those tables.

I am new to pl.sql and trying to learn the syntax.

I wasn't sure if you could,

```
DECLARE
n_first 
n_last
   BEGIN 
   SELECT * FROM name_s
   n_fisrt := 'Thomas'||n_first; 

        dbms_output.put_line(n_first)
    END;
/
Desired Output: 'Thomas'
```

I understand that this is not syntactically correct but I am just trying to pick up on how you can use data from your existing tables to get this sort of desired output

EDIT: The above table is hypothetical and only contains two columns for this example. Now using real tables and data.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
begin
for cur_r in (select loc_t from loc_t_matrix where store_s in(1,2,3,4,5); loop
dbms_output.put_line('Hello store' || cur_r.loc_traits );
end loop;
end;
/
```

The above does not compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need something like this

```
declare    
      v_authName author.author_last_name%type;    
   begin    
     select    
        author_last_name into v_authName    
      from    
        author    
      where   
        author_key = 'A103';    
     dbms_output.put_line('Name: '||v_authName);    
   end;    
/



Name: weaton
```

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_pl_sql_plsql_select_into_clause.htm

Answer (score 0):

As tables usually contain more than one row, I presume that NAME_S also contains several rows. In that case, the simplest option to display those names is a cursor FOR loop (Google for it). For example:

```
begin
  for cur_r in (select n_first, n_last from name_s) loop
    dbms_output.put_line('Hello ' || cur_r.n_first ||' '||cur_r.n_last);
  end loop;
end;
/
```

As you can see, you don't need local variables in that case.

If you used your SELECT ... INTO (as suggested by mCeviker), that would work unless it raises TOO-MANY-ROWS (as you can't put all rows' names into a single variable).